# using showModalDialog with hyperlink in code behind

Tags: web-part

I am using the following code to call the javascript function but the cursor is not showing when I hover over the link.
Any idea how to make this code work?

```
lnkUpload.Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript:ShowServerInformation('" + libraryID + "')";

<script>
    function ShowServerInformation(libraryID) {

        var options = {
            url: '_layouts/Upload.aspx?List=' + libraryID + '&IsDlg=1',
            tite: 'Server Information',
            allowMaximize: false,
            showClose: true,
            width: 600,
        };

        SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

use the following to create the dialog!

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

no need for execute method as it should be refeneced witin masterpage to load in order!

```
<Sharepoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" Name="sp.ui.dialog.js" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" runat="server"></Sharepoint:ScriptLink>           
<SharePoint:FormDigest runat="server" />
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410058(v=office.14).aspx

**EDIT**

lol ok you want to change from a text cursor to a pointer? have this code within your js file:

```
  document.getElementById("element ID goes here").setAttribute("style", "cursor:url(file for cursor path.cur);")
```

so for `getElementById` you need to out in the ID of the url not the class name but the ID name. The last part to change is `url` where you need to put in the path of the cursor your going to be using to show!

as an example: I have a url control tag with id "myURL" and iv saved an image of the cursor on layouts/images folder:

```
  document.getElementById("myURL").setAttribute("style", "cursor:url(/_Layouts/images/pointer.cur);")
```

this is only a work around as it should show the pointer cursor when you hover over the url, have you tested on another machine to make sure its just your machine that its doing it on? have you also tried different browsers? im asking as you need to make sure its only local to your pc or browser.

Comment: Hi Ali, thanks for your reply. I made the correction in my code but I still get the "I" cursor when I hover the link.

Comment: just ammended my answer!

Comment: I added this in my page so it shows the hand cursor a { cursor: pointer; }. I could not find a better solution.